# Mysql find distinct values from rows matching multiple values in another field

Tags: mysql

In a table I have records as follows:

```
ID, ID1, ID2
1, 2, 3
2, 2, 4
3, 2, 5
4, 3, 3
4, 3, 4
4, 4, 3
4, 4, 4
4, 4, 5
```

I want to be able to find all ID1 values which exist in the table which have ALL of the ID2 values 3, 4 AND 5

So in this case I would want some SQL to pull out only ID1 = 2 and ID1 = 4, but not ID1 = 3 because there exist only ID2=3 and ID2=4 for ID1=3... so it's missing a row for ID2=5 and hence I do not want it included in my result set.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

TY!

Comment: CAN YOU BE CLEAR. GIVE SAMPLE OUTPUTS YOU NEED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use the following which selects all rows that have an `id2` with a value of 3, 4 or 5 and then applies a group by with a having clause to make sure that you return 3 distinct `id2` values:

```
select id1
from yourtable
where id2 in (3, 4, 5)
group by id1
having count(distinct id2) = 3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61bd7/2).

This type of query is known as [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).